# How can i add more sources to helm-find-files?

Tags: helm-sources

I want `C-x C-f` which is mapped to `helm-find-files` to include

1. X amount of recently opened files
2. Files in the X number of unique directories as recently opened files
3. Files in recent projects, ie git, svn projects e.g helm-projectile
4. A manually configured list of directories

I don't know how to go about it and I came across an example from this blog

Following an example at http://blog.jenkster.com/2013/10/finding-files-in-emacs-helm.html

```
(helm :sources '(helm-source-findutils
                 helm-source-ls-git
                 helm-source-locate)
      :buffer "*helm-find-files*")
```

If I want to accomplish do I need some additional source which be
add to the list above? How will they be implemented?

If it is not possible with helm what other package can accomplish this?